# How do i deal with responsive menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a responsive menu but texts are coming down when im resizing my website.

When i'm resizing to a lower dimension like 637 x 400  "a empresa" "projetos" and "contato" they drop and come down.

```css
nav {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #a23286;
    color: #eee;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
}
/* menu + logo dimensoes */
nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

nav li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 17px 0;
    color: #eee;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #a23286;
}

nav a#openup {
    display: none;
}
```

Should i just create a query in css for this state and change the font of the text?

https://codepen.io/rfop2/pen/JjjBBRe

Comment: Please include enough HTML, CSS, and JavaScript to reproduce the issue **in the question here on Stack Overflow**, not just on an external site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do a lot of the things you can do on CodePen right here (the icon in the post editor toolbar looks like a page with `<>` in it).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a media query and set the interval between 400px and 637px and set the width of `nav a` to 85px.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 637px) and (min-width: 400px)  {
  nav a {
    width: 85px;
  }
}
```

Your codepen: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/hevar/pen/PooBBOz)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use css flex for this. See ul style below.

```
nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: no-wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```js
$(function() {
    menu = $("nav ul");
  
    $("#openup").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      menu.slideToggle();
    });
  
    $(window).resize(function() {
      var w = $(this).width();
      if (w > 480 && menu.is(":hidden")) {
        menu.removeAttr("style");
      }
    });
  
    $("nav li").on("click", function(e) {
      var w = $(window).width();
      if (w < 480) {
        menu.slideToggle();
      }
    });
    $(".open-menu").height($(window).height());
  });
  
  $('.cf a').on('click', function(event){
    if(this.hash !== ''){
      event.preventDefault();
  
      const hash = this.hash;
  
      $('html, body').animate(
        {
          scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
        },
        800,
        function(){
          window.location.hash = hash;
        }
      );
    }
  });
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web&display=swap');

/* corpo geral */

body {
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.6;
}

/* menu */

nav {
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #a23286;
    color: #eee;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
}
/* menu + logo dimensoes */
nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: no-wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

nav li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 17px 0;
    color: #eee;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  border-bottom: 5px solid #a23286;
}

nav a#openup {
    display: none;
}

/* logo no menu */

.logo{
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
}

.textoIn{
  background-color: #a23286;
  height: 400px;
}


h1{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: black;
}

/* texto abaixo do menu */

@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {

    nav {
      height: auto;
      border-bottom: 0;
    }
    nav ul {
      display: none;
      height: auto;
    }
    nav li {
      width: 100%;
      float: left;
      position: relative;
    }
    nav a {
      text-align: left;
      width: 100%;
      text-indent: 25px;
      background: #a23286;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
    }
    nav a:hover {
      background-color: #a23286;
    }
    nav a#openup:after {
      content: "|||";
      transform: rotate(-90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      /* IE 9 */
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      /* Safari and Chrome */
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      right: 5px;
      top: 20px;
    }
    nav a#openup {
      display: block;
      background-color: #a23286;
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
    }
  }
  .cf:before, .cf:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
  }
  
  .cf:after {
    clear: both;
  }
  
  .cf {
    zoom: 1;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>JRConecte</title>
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Menu  -->
    <div id="Menu">
      <header>
        <nav class='cf'>
          <ul class='cf'> 
            <div class = "logo"> 
              <img src="./img/logojrc.png">
            </div>
            <li>
                <a href="#home">INICIO</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href='#atuacao'>ATUAÇÃO</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href='#equipe'>EQUPE</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href='#empresa'>A EMPRESA</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href='#projetos'>PROJETOS</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                  <a href='#contato'>CONTATO</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <a href='#' id='openup'>JRConecte</a>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
    </div>
    <!-- Texto inicial -->
   <div id="home">
     <div class='textoIn'>
        <h1>
            asdasdasddsadaasdasdsadadadsa
        </h1>
     </div>
   </div>
    <!-- Areas de Atuacao -->
    <div>
    </div>
    <!-- Nossa Equipe -->
    <div></div>
    <!-- A empresa -->
    <div>
    </div>
    <!-- Nossos Projetos-->
    <div> </div>
    <!-- Depoimentos -->
    <div></div>
    <!-- Fale Conosco -->
    <div> </div>
    <!-- Redes Socias -->
    <div></div>

    <script
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
    integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```